# How do I remove the title bar from my app?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app there is this title bar at the top where the overflow menu would be, but I don't need settings and only have one screen.
When I change the theme like described in many other questions I get the old 2.2 theme. I want to have the modern theme just without the bar at the top.

Answer (score 190):

Go to styles.xml and change `.DarkActionBar` for `.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

becomes

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

if colors are irrelevant to your app, you can actually go for

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: Works as expected. However, the title is also gone when viewing all active apps.

Comment: how would you fix that @IAbstract ?

Comment: @PabloBiedma: I don't know.

Answer (score 72):

In the manifest file Change:

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: While this works, editing the `styles.xml` file might be a better option for most, as using this method ignores any values which may have been set up under `AppTheme` in the `styles.xml` file.  The solution below which replaces the parent class with `NoActionBar` within the `styles.xml` file preserves any pre-existing style information which has been set up.

Comment: In that case my entire app background goint to be black

Comment: That was worked for me thank you.

Answer (score 26):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

works in `onCreate()` when put before `setContentView()` is invoked.

otherwise it crashes

Comment: This causes app to crash.

I put the line in between
`super.onCreate.....`
and
`setContentView.....`

And it crashes

Comment: This is not the correct way to do it. Mr. Torres  explained it well.

Answer (score 21):

Check this

```java
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: This is working code to hide the bar by a program itself. Could be placed in constructor `onCreate(...)` after the `super.onCreate(..)` and `setContentView(...)` lines to hide bar just after program is started.

Answer (score 16):

In **styles.xml** file, change **DarkActionBar** to **NoActionBar**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Answer (score 15):

This works for me

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 15):

Go to Project -> app -> main -> res -> values -> styles.xml

Change this line if you want to delete it for every view

```
 `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`
```

to

```
 `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`
```

if you want to make it just for one view you can change it in youre manifest data. Go to Android -> manifests -> AndroidManifest.xml. do following:

1. Search the View you want to get this type of change `<activity android:name"...">`
2. Add `android:theme=""@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

   ---

Comment: I like this solution. Unlike setting NoActionBar in the manifest which forces you to remove any already applied theme (or style) e.g. Theme.MyApp, with this solution one can edit Theme.MyApp and preserve few customization.

Answer (score 12):

This was working for me on `values/styles.xml` add items:

```xml
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> make error

Answer (score 10):

In the manifest file change to this:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
```

Answer (score 6):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Just simply put `getSupportActionBar().hide();`
between `super.onCreate` and `setContentView` method.

Answer (score 5):

1. open styles.xml
2. insert

> ```
>  <style name="no_title" parent="AppTheme">
>         <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
>         <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
>  </style>
> ```

you can change name="---------"

3. open Androidmaifest.xm

   find  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" chang to  android:theme="@style/no_title"
4. click select Theme on menubar (it's green color near MainActivity)

   - click project Theme
   - click no_title (on you right hand Side)
   - click OK

Answer (score 5):

For Beginner Like Me. Just Do it what I say.From your Android Project.

**app -> res -> values -> style.xml**

replace this code

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

do this in you manifest file:

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Comment: it switches me to the old android design (black background,  textboxes with yellow borders...)

Comment: try `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"` make sure you are using api level min 14.

Comment: You can use this for a light theme:

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >

Answer (score 3):

delete the following from activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

[contact me for more help](http://wedesign.comxa.com)

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions replaced styles.xml with  themes.xml

Go to Project -> app -> res -> values -> themes -> themes.xml

and change e.g.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- omitted for brevity -->
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- omitted for brevity. -->
</style>
```

Switching the parent to **NoActionBar**

Do this for both themes.xml files

Answer (score 2):

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

in onCreate() works!

Answer (score 2):

Try  changing styles to NoActionBar if that doesn't works add this code to your main activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me i hope this work for you as well

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use actionbar function `setTitle()` if you wish to show logo or have some other stuff in you actionBar but dont want to see name of the app, write this code in MainActivity.java or anywhere you wish to hide title in `onCreate`:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.full_white_logo_m); // display logo
actionBar.setTitle(""); // hide title
```

This way your app won't have reason to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setTitle(null)` above

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The title will disappear then you can use the logo of your choice.....

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just double click on this button and choose "NoTitleBar" .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To simply remove the title bar (which means the bar contains your app name) from an activity, I simply add below line to that activity in the `manifests\AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

It should now look like below

```
<activity
  android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

Hope it'll be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem as you, and solve this problem just by changing the class which I extended.

```
//you will get the app that does not have a title bar at the top.
import android.app.Activity;
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{}

//you will get the app that has title bar at top
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, this is how to do.

```
val actionBar: ActionBar? = supportActionBar
    actionBar?.hide()
```

Comment: What is this 'supportActionBar' variable?

Answer (score 1):

At Project tab, find

> app>res >values > themes >theme.xml

[image]
Change the value of parent in the above shown image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Change in themes.xml

res/values/themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` of your application you'll find the `android:theme` for example set to `@style/AppTheme`

Now go to `styles.xml`, find the style tag, make sure that name is set to `AppTheme` the same as in manifest and set parent to `android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`
(also do this in styles(v21) if you have it in your project)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call  `setTitle(null);` in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

try: 
toolbar.setTitle(" ");

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

New versions of Android Studio have `themes.xml` instead of `styles.xml`. So go to `res/values/themems/themes.xml` and change `.DarkActionBar` to `.NoActionBar`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This also solved my problem, but before it did I couldn't find the styles.xml resource.

Eventually I found a solution and it turns out that the theme attribute is now inside the themes.xml not the styles.xml [Here is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFp9l.png)