# App's name doesn't show up in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio doesn't show the app's name:

[image]

In the screenshot, you can see that the app's name is not visible. How can I fix it?

Comment: where do you want your app name to be?

Comment: You need to add toolbar theme in your style..

Comment: that should be on the top left corner

Comment: Mohamed Mohaideen AH , how to do that? actually I am beginner and stucked.please help

Comment: You can reverse what is done in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492522/how-do-i-remove-the-title-bar-in-android-studio

Comment: Kindly check your style.xml file, change your theme to have a action bar by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking to want app name in left top corner?
[image]

[image]

Just change app theme as defaultTheme in layout for application name shows in layout view

Comment: no, I did mean in the constraints layout's top left corner

Comment: did you try to change app theme as default

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue by setting in `"View Options"` the `"Show System UI"` option:

[image: Setting Android Studio View Options to show AppName in Layout]

Answer (score 2):

Check your style.xml file under `res->values->style.xml`

The style theme will be as followes:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

You need to check if the `parent` has the value `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. It **should not have** something like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` where app`s  your title will not be visible as there is no action bar itself.

Comment: mine is :  "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: I actually edited 'Base' earlier there because previously there was nothing showing in app preview .

Answer (score 0):

You can done using like this..

Create new project & set basic activity in template will give the project with toolbar & appname will shown in toolbar.

> File->New Project->Next->Next->Select Basic Activity template(Default its select empty activity)->Finish.

Another Way if you want to view temporarly to see your app name select theme with name contain ActionBar like DarkActionBar you can get the desired results.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem can occur when you use too long app name. Try making the app name shorter. I had the same issue and that was my problem.