# Android Studio (3.3.1). Layout decorations are not visible

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Im learning Android studio now and encounter this problem with Layout Preview. I cant see phone frame.Ok, it's not big deal, but in result I see that the toolbar was not counted in design. For better understanding look at picture [Virtual Device and Layout preview comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzTMl.png). For layout preview and virtual device I picked Nexus 6. Screen sizes should be exactly the same. In the picture you can see the button in the layout preview. But in the virtual device the button is almost completely out of the screen bounds.

This is a link to my app
[HelloWorldApp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fi28g41c5si2jas/HelloWorldApp.zip?dl=0)

Comment: you can remove the title bar, [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492522/how-do-i-remove-the-title-bar-in-android-studio)

Comment: There is <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKS!!!

Click that 'eye' icon and select the 'Show layout decorations'. Done.

---

Try this,

Click on Preview-> `Visibility Symbol` which named as `view options`

There is one option, `Show Layout Decorations` , Select this options.

For reference find below image:

[image]

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select device and theme for your preview window see attached image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB0QG.png

Comment: Unforunately, there is no such simple solution

Answer (score 0):

In the new version, you can see this feature in the 'layout validation' vertical bar on the right.

[image]