# How to fix this UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am relatively new to Android Studio. I was creating an app which plays music on touch. The app works but I want to remove this element from the UI so that it looks full screen.

This is how it appears in the design window:

[image]

This is my styles XML file`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

[This is how the image looks on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csl7v.png):

What I want is, I want to see the exact design on the UI design window. Also, I would like my app to look fullscreen, without the name bar.

Comment: Use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar Instead of Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: @Kevan He wants to remove Toolbar so use `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` or `Base.Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the "Title Bar" (the Name Bar) you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492522/how-do-i-remove-the-title-bar-in-android-studio).

> I want to see the exact design on the UI design window

There should be error messages telling you why the Layout Designer in Android Studio is not displaying the UI, it could be a library/Gradle issue. or It could be caused by the styles.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your style

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

This will hide action bar