# How to remove top status bar black background

Tags: android, fullscreen, statusbar, appcompatactivity

I'd like to create a TRUE fullscreen activity, but there is always a black status bar on screen top. Android 9.0.

I've tried almost all I can find with Google and existing Apps with similar jobs. Manifest, code, style, AS sample fullscreen activity, all were tried.

styles.xml:

```xml
    <style name="AppThemeA" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

Manifest:

```xml
<activity android:name=".ScreenActivity" android:theme="@style/AppThemeA" />
```

Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Kotlin (commented lines are tried and failed):

```
class ScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDetector)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        //window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        //window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
        //window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        /*
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                )*/

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_detector)
        ...
    }
}
```

The expected result:
[image: expected]

What I actually got:
[image: actual]

[[[[ Solution ]]]]

Found what caused this. You should set the App to FullScreen App in Settings -> Display.

https://www.gottabemobile.com/how-to-enable-full-screen-apps-on-galaxy-s10

So fixed. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You can comment on each individual answer to say if it did not work, rather than updating the question.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492522/how-do-i-remove-the-title-bar-in-android-studio/53792380#53792380

Comment: try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341818/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-status-bar-in-android/39341866

Comment: try this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar) It will help you lot.

Answer (score 22):

I had a problem with displaying content through the notch or the cutout area. Found this in the docs:

> LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES - Content renders into the cutout area in both portrait and landscape modes.

Key thing for me was this line in the activity style:

```
// Important to draw through the cutouts
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

I wanted to show an image in immersive mode, and when I click it, the system UI (status & navigation bars) should show up.

Here is my complete solution:

1- Methods to show/hide system UI in the Activity

```
private fun hideSystemUI() {
    sysUIHidden = true
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE 
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // Hide nav bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // Hide status bar
            )
}


private fun showSystemUI() {
    sysUIHidden = false
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION // layout Behind nav bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN // layout Behind status bar
            )
}
```

2- Make sure this in the root view of your xml layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

3- The Style for the Full screen Activity will give status/navigation bars a semi transparent background when they show up:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#50000000</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#50000000</item>
    // Important to draw behind cutouts
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item> 
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sysTransparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I am using immersive mode, it works well with all devices except Samsung that always display a black status bar. `windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode` helps to solve it, crazy android :D

Answer (score 19):

Add this method in your activity

```
public static void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

before adding this call this below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` `onCreate`

```
    hideSystemUI();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    }
```

above attribute is use if your device have notch cutout for camera.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Nothing else worked for me.

Comment: This is so simple and working, Nothing else worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me and this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is deprecated, according to the docs you should use `WindowInsetsController`. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/q/62577645/4544940

Comment: Last line helped me to stop status bar blacking out on MIUI 13 (API 31)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your code you just need adding this code before your setContentView in your activity

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yukwno2GBoI) video I got the solution.

First of all app theme should extend a NoActionBar Theme

```
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"></style>
```

There after in the Activity onCreate Method (In this case using viewBinding) should implemented as follows.

```
private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager
              .LayoutParams
              .LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
    }

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, binding.root).let { controller ->

        controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat
            .BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE

    }

    setContentView(binding.root)

}
```

This worked for me. Hope it does for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to implement the edge-to-edge display starting from Android Q. The code is inspired by this [blog](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/gesturalnav#edge-to-edge).

First, in your `styles.xml`, modify the `AppTheme` like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Suppose, we need to make the `MainActivity` fullscreen, then in `MainActivity.kt`:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                )
```

Also, check the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#immersive) for enabling fullscreen mode.

Comment: Tried, failed. Samsung S10+.

Comment: Which Android version you were using?

Comment: Samsung S10+, Android Pie

Answer (score 0):

First, in your styles.xml, modify the AppTheme like:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and also mention in your manifest file.

```
<activity
   android:name=".activities.FullViewActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window window = mContext.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    int statusBarHeight = (int) dpToPx(24);

    View view = new View(mContext);
    view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.getLayoutParams().height = statusBarHeight;
    ((ViewGroup) window.getDecorView()).addView(view);
     view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
}
```

**dpToPx**

```
public float dpToPx(float dp) {
    return (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```