# True Fullscreen not working with AppCompat theme in Android?

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I'm trying to create a splashcreen for my android application. I'm using an AppCompat theme, and I read that to have it fullscreen, I have to use in my style.xml theme (which I did):

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

With that, my application starts in fullscreen in the sense that when it starts, there is a white screen (in fullscreen) that appears before my splashscreen.

However, when my splashscreen starts, there is a black bar on top (which is where the status bar is) (cf screenshot)

[image: Splashscreen]

My splashscreen is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
        tools:context=".ui.activity.SplashscreenActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_galagomusic"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to add in the splashscreen activity:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.decorView.apply {
            // Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
            // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
            // a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
            // hide the navigation bar.
            systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        }
        supportActionBar?.hide()


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen)
}
```

But it still doesn't work.

I'm not sure what is going on here, if anybody can help, that would be great.

Thanks.

**Edit:** It seems to be related to this issue: [How to remove top status bar black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353716/how-to-remove-top-status-bar-black-background)

This issue come from the phone itself, which allow or not some application to go fullscreen.

https://www.gottabemobile.com/how-to-enable-full-screen-apps-on-galaxy-s10/

Is there a way to override that?