# When hide State Bar, it turns black

Tags: android, android-studio, uinavigationbar, fullscreen

> I am trying to hide (**state bar** and **navigation bar**) on my **splash**
> **screen** , but it turned to **black state** like photo below.

[image]

My style code:

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/color_navigation_bar</item>
    </style>
```

And my java code :

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
        Window window = this.getWindow();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) { // API 30
            window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
        } else {
//            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }
```

I am trying with this code also but still black :

```
this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

> Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395206/9903675) solve my problem.

Do those three parts and will done:

1- Methods to show/hide system UI in the Activity

```
private fun hideSystemUI() {
    sysUIHidden = true
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE 
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // Hide nav bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // Hide status bar
            )
}


private fun showSystemUI() {
    sysUIHidden = false
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION // layout Behind nav bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN // layout Behind status bar
            )
}
```

2- Make sure this in the root view of your xml layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

3- The Style for the Full screen Activity will give status/navigation bars a semi transparent background when they show up:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#50000000</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#50000000</item>
    // Important to draw behind cutouts
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item> 
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sysTransparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

the most important , add this line in the activity style

```
// Important to draw through the cutouts
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353716/how-to-remove-top-status-bar-black-background/61395206#61395206) ,it will help you